# Replace text with Array In php

Tags: php

I tried to replace `{{array}}` with

```
$array = array(
  'index'  => 1,
  'value'  => 'John Doe'
);

$fileName           =   resource_path().'/custom-stub/custom.stub';
$datatable_data     =   file_get_contents($fileName);
$datatable_data     =   str_replace('{{first_name}}', 'Linda',  $datatable_data); // Replace text
$datatable_data     =   str_replace('{{array}}',      $array,   $datatable_data); // Replace array (but not working)
```

How can i replace the text(shortcode) with array in file.

Comment: Arrays do not have a string representation. What do you want to be displayed there?

Comment: What is the expected output of the replacement statement you are looking for?

Comment: Like suppose 
This is the file 
https://pasteboard.co/K4zGMv6.png

and this is how i want it 
https://pasteboard.co/K4zH45L.png

on the place of {{array}}
it will replace the array 

First i get the content of a txt file then replace the string with str_Replace
but now i want to replace the array with string 

from above two picture you will understand my problem
@El_Vanja

Comment: I would recommend including this information in textual form in the question itself. Links can breka in the future and then your question will lack necessary context. As for the solution, I believe Duroth's answer covers what you need.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to replace placeholders in a file, so that the replaced value is valid PHP code, then you need to wrap the variables in [`var_export()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.var-export.php) calls.

Example:

```php
<?php

$string = 'Johnny';
$float = 3.1;
$array = [1, 2, 3];

$phpString = <<<'EOL'
  $allData = [ {{string}}, {{float}}, {{array}} ];
EOL;

// strtr() or str_replace(), doesn't matter which.
$replacedPhpString = strtr($phpString, [
  '{{string}}' => var_export($string, true),
  '{{float}}' => var_export($float, true),
  '{{array}}' => var_export($array, true),
]);

echo $replacedPhpString;
```

Outputs:

> $allData = [ 'Johnny', 3.1, array (
> 0 => 1,
> 1 => 2,
> 2 => 3,
> ) ];

Note the second parameter to `var_export()` makes the function *return* the value instead of *printing* it.